# Rails: Find object with just the ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am building an app that uses the PublicActivity gem (https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity), although this gem is a nice way to have a "Facebook"-like activity stream, it also comes at a small price; Database load time.

To help with load time, I am offloading the processing to my `Sidekiq` processor like so:

`ActivityLogWorker.perform_async object_id: @video.id, klass: :video, owner_id: @athlete.id, activity: :create`

Here is my worker:

```
class ActivityLogWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :activity_log

  def perform(opts = {})
    obj = "#{opts.delete('klass')}".capitalize.constantize.find(opts.delete('object_id'))
    owner = User.find(opts.delete('owner_id'))
    activity = opts.delete('activity').to_sym
    obj.create_activity activity, owner: owner
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to pass in the `object_id` without having to clarify the class that goes along with that object?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what counts as "better", but you could just pass the object itself and have your worker query it for its id and its class.

Comment: As long as you don't use the instance right away and that you use it to do the query.

Comment: @bgates - The problem with passing complex objects to a Worker is that things get "muddied" up when errors occur. Having quick and easy identifiers help with diagnosing problems

Comment: OK, how about `object_which_is_a_video_id`, then a regular expression to pull out the class name? Or if you will never have more `_id` parameters than you list, find the owner (and delete `owner_id`) first, then the only other `_id` will be `video_id` or `audio_id` etc.